# Unable to type in ios simulator

Tags: react-native, expo, ios-simulator

I'm building a React Native expo app and have a search bar where I am unable to type using my MacBooks keyboard. I am able to use the simulator keyboard and I am also able to copy and paste from the Mac keyboard.
I'm using Simulator version 15.0. I've toggled Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard. I restarted the simulator and restarted the server.
What else should I try?

Comment: "...restarted the server..." - *what* server?

Comment: @ScottHunter the Metro bundler.

Comment: What is your language keyboard on macOS and in iOS simulator?

Comment: @VasylNahuliak it’s an English keyboard. I tried changing it to French but same issue. I also found an old external keyboard and nothing unfortunately.